# Connect ipcam directly to pc

Tags: video-streaming, ip-camera

I have a sport establishment.
I have two soccer fiels, with pc and ip cam on each.

I would like to connect my IP CAM directly to my PC, not to the router, because its a mobile network router and the connectivity is very bad, so i can't record the stream in good quality (i use ffmpeg on my pc to record the stream).

Can-i do this ? (sorry for my poor english)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can assign static IP to your PC which is in range of IP camera, now connect IP camera to your PC and try to ping camera from PC . If you are able to ping then you can record.
Alternatively, you can connect both the IP camera and PC to the same switch and it should work as well, if both camera and PC connected to same switch there won't be a bandwidth problem.

Comment: Thanks for you repli.
Can you do that for me, i can pay you for that if you have professionnal statment.

I have anydesk installed on it.